# Verifying Authenticode signed executables and DLLs using OpenSSL API

Tags: cryptography, authentication, public-key-infrastructure, digital-signature, openssl

I have installed **openssl** and now the **rsa_test.c** is running fine. What I want to do is:

1. Open any exe or dll digital certificate. Extract the **Thumbprint** and **PublicKey**.
   The public key contains the **exponent** too (if you are familiar with ASN1 encoding).
2. Now I have already calculated **SHA-1** hash of the file and compared it to the MD field to find it correct. So now I want to pass the **Thumbprint**, **PublicKey->m** and **PublicKey->e** to **RSA_public_decrypt** function to calculate the decrypted **SHA-1** hash of the file.

What **Padding Algorithm** should I pass to the function? When I pass **RSA_NO_PADDING**, it decrypts but give me the 128-bytes long hash which is not at all correct. For all other padding algorithm options it returns the error of padding not found.

Would you please teach me or tell me the correct parameters to pass through the function with an example or good link to example?